# Splash screen de un gif en react-native

Tags: android, react-native

estoy realizando una aplicación con react native con código nativo de android y ios, en las especificaciones de la aplicación es requerido un splash screen con un GiF, ya he insertado de la documentación de react native las dependencias requeridas

```
dependencies {
  // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'

  // For animated GIF support
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'

  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:2.1.0'
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.0.0'

  // For WebP support, without animations
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.0.0'
}
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.60/image#gif-and-webp-support-on-android

El soporte para GIF funciona correctamente dentro las screen/componentes. Sin embargo cuando intento colocar el GIF en el splash screen no funciona, queda una imagen estatica del GIF

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <bitmap
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/splash_screen2"/>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

¿Como puedo color un splash screen en formato gif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como "Splash" no se puede, lo que se hace normalmente es dejar una imagen estatica en el Splash (ideal la misma del gif, o el color de fondo) y crear un componente Splash con un setTimeout con el gif